# delegate = self causes Thread 1: exc_bad_instruction (code=exc_i386_invop subcode=0x0)

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, self, exc-bad-instruction

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate = self // error occurs here
}
```

Comment: Most likely you didn't connect the table view to the outlet in your storyboard.

Comment: Please show us more code. This does not tell us if your class conforms the Protocol needed for the TableViewDelegate.

Comment: @BennX It's a runtime error so we know the class already conforms. If it didn't the code wouldn't compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your `@IBOutlet tableView` is properly connected with interface builder.